# ExpressJS + React Native + MongoDB for creating mobile and Web?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, api, express

What do you use on making website and mobile apps in one project?

Someone advice this:

1. Express JS for Website
2. React Native for Mobile app
3. MongoDB for database

Do you have any experience to build other way?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "the best and easy way" is pretty much opinion based. Question like this are not suitable for StackOverflow. Please read this [what to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: hi i already edit the question thanks